# Error SQLSTATE[HY000] on placing order

Tags: magento-1.9, database, orders, sql

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away, query was.After placing order getting error

i am getting error below error after placing order:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away, query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `sales_flat_order` AS `main_table` WHERE (main_table.customer_id = '12137') AND (state IN('new', 'processing', 'complete', 'closed', 'canceled', 'holded', 'payment_review')
```

[image]

How can I fix this error.

Answer (score 1):

This means, that your code waits to long before sending the statement to the SQL server (or it crashed).

- Check dmesg whether your SQL server or client crashed (if yes, get more ram ore reduce memory usage)
- if it didn't, increase wait_timeout in /etc/mysql/my.cnf as temporary fix
- analyse your code with a profiler like tideways or blackfire for permanent fix